# What is the purpose of TIME WAIT in TCP connection tear down?

Tags: tcp

I found that the reason the active closer enters TIME WAIT is to make sure that the final ACK is not lost. But how does it know if the final ACK is lost? Will the passive closer resend the FIN and then the active closer knows the ACK was lost? Here is a picture of the TCP FSM.

[image: TCP FSM]

Comment: [TCP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transmission_Control_Protocol)

Comment: This blog post has a great answer: https://vincent.bernat.im/en/blog/2014-tcp-time-wait-state-linux#purpose

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> Will the passive closer resend the FIN and then the active closer
>   knows the ACK was lost?

Yes. Quoting from *TCP/IP Illustrated Volume 1*, in the TCP Connection Management section:

> 3. To complete the close, the final segment contains an ACK for the last FIN. Note that if a FIN is lost, it is retransmitted until an ACK
>      for it is received.

There is a timeout. When in `LAST_ACK`, the passive closer will resend `FIN` when there is a timeout, assuming that it was lost. If it was indeed lost, then the active closer will eventually receive the retransmitted `FIN` and enter `TIME_WAIT`. If the `FIN` was not lost but the final `ACK` was lost, then the active closer is in `TIME_WAIT` and receives `FIN` again. When this happens - receiving a `FIN` in `TIME_WAIT` - the `ACK` is retransmitted.

The timeout value in `TIME_WAIT` is *NOT* used for retransmission purposes. When there is a timeout in `TIME_WAIT`, it is assumed that the final `ACK` was successfully delivered because the passive closer didn't retransmit `FIN` packets. So, the timeout in `TIME_WAIT` is just an amount of time after which we can safely assume that if the other end didn't send anything, then it's because he received the final `ACK` and closed the connection.

Answer (score 2):

The purpose of TIME_WAIT is to allow the networking to distinguish packets that arrive as belong to the 'old, existing' connection from a new one.  The recommendation is to set the TIME_WAIT timer to twice the Maximum Segment Lifetime (MSL), on my system the MSL is 1 minute, so connections linger in the TIME_WAIT state for 2 minutes.

After this amount of time any packets that arrive are no longer associated with the old connection.

TIME_WAIT is not directly waited to sending ACK packets; that is driven by the CLOSE_WAIT and FIN_WAIT states.  When you get to TIME_WAIT state the socket is already closed.

References: http://www.tcpipguide.com/free/t_TCPConnectionTermination-3.htm https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maximum_segment_lifetime http://www.lognormal.com/blog/2012/09/27/linux-tcpip-tuning/

Answer (score 1):

> But how does it know if the final ACK is lost?

Because it didn't receive it within the timeout period. I know that's a "duh" answer, but that's exactly why these states and timeouts exist.

> Will the passive closer resend the FIN

No. Not unless further packets arrive for that stream, and that would result in "RST" (reset) being sent.

The whole process is complicated state machine to execute an orderly shutdown despite the possibility of network failures. Networks break, links experience errors, links become saturated and have to drop packets, devices fail, etc.  As an exercise, run the state tree for an active connection when one of the endpoints just disappears (eg. power failure.)

TL;DR That state tree is designed to handle every possible failure mode.

Comment: Thanks, but I'm still confused about the first part. I meant how does the active closer know the ACK was not received by the passive closer? When the passive closer receives the ACK, it just tears down its side of the connection, and if it doesn't receive the ACK, it just stays in LAST ACK, so how does the active closer know if the ACK was received?

Comment: because there are timers attached to every state.

Comment: Sorry I'm not understanding. How do these timers tell the active closer that the passive closer did not receive the final ACK? i.e. how does the active closer know if it has to resend the final ACK?