# What is "TIME_WAIT" connection in a TCP connection and what is it's purpose?

Tags: tcp, internet, transport-protocol, osi

I am requesting a webpage running on local server port 8080 and was expecting one connection to be established between the server (port 8080) and client (random port). But one additional port is also getting created and connecting to the server with `TIME_WAIT` as status. So just wondering what is this time wait connection about?

Before connection to the webserver

```
netstat -ntap | grep 8080
tcp6       0      0 :::8080                 :::*                    LISTEN      104965/java
```

After connecting to the web page which returned result immediately.

```
netstat -ntap | grep 8080
tcp6       0      0 :::8080                 :::*                    LISTEN      104965/java         
tcp6       0      0 ::1:8080                ::1:53950               ESTABLISHED 104965/java         
tcp6       0      0 ::1:53948               ::1:8080                TIME_WAIT   -                   
tcp6       0      0 ::1:53950               ::1:8080                ESTABLISHED 20656/_Postman --no
```

Port `53950` is the client random port to speak to server and this is understandable.

**But what is the function of port `53948` with status `TIME_WAIT`.**

After about one minute the port `53948` connection to server is closed. But the port `54950`  moves to `TIME_WAIT` status.

```
netstat -ntap | grep 8080
tcp6       0      0 :::8080                 :::*                    LISTEN      104965/java         
tcp6       0      0 ::1:8080                ::1:53950               TIME_WAIT   -
```

After about few minutes - a new port (54008) is open and is in `TIME_WAIT` status.

```
netstat -ntap | grep 8080
tcp6       0      0 :::8080                 :::*                    LISTEN      104965/java         
tcp6       0      0 ::1:54008               ::1:8080                TIME_WAIT   -
```

After about 5 minutes - all of the ports are closed

```
 netstat -ntap | grep 8080
tcp6       0      0 :::8080                 :::*                    LISTEN      104965/java
```

**Could someone explain what `TIME_WAIT` is about and why 2 additional ports are required.**

Comment: Have you tried [RFC 793](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc793)?

Comment: @zac67, thx. How about the additional ports - would the RFC capture this too. I will appreciate if u can summarize in to an answer. RFC's are generally not English :-) for every one.

Comment: There is a clear diagram on page 23 that explains the different states and how to get to them.

Comment: A new socket connection uses a new ephemeral port - possibly, there's a redirect. Try your browser's network/diagnostic tools, `wget`, `curl`, or similar. Also, what you're *really* asking about is the workings of HTTP which are off-topic here as an application-layer protocol...

Comment: Yes, RFC's may look like an alien language, but they are perfectly clear english. I know reading is hard, and it's a long block of monospaced text, but it is very clearly documented.

Comment: @ricky, agree with u. It just takes bit of time and patience + intel

Comment: Granted, it might take someone a while to zero in on RFC 793, but it took me a faction of a second to search for TIME WAIT ("TIME-WAIT") to highlight the text in my answer. (I'd vote to close this if "lack of research" were still a close reason)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the purpose of TIME WAIT in TCP connection tear down?](https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/19581/what-is-the-purpose-of-time-wait-in-tcp-connection-tear-down) (literally the first google result, superuser answer from 2010 is 2nd)

Comment: I don't think this addresses the additional port issue which is also my concern @ricky

Comment: Connections are constantly being created/closed/destroyed. You're just catching them in those various states. (web traffic isn't normally a long lived, persistent socket.) As this is a localhost socket, you're seeing both ends.

Comment: @ricky, port 53948 is my concern. What's is it's purpose.

Comment: Did any answer help you? If so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you can post and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 1):

```
TIME-WAIT - represents waiting for enough time to pass to be sure
the remote TCP received the acknowledgment of its connection
termination request.
```

[[RFC 792, p.22]](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc793#page-22)

The purpose is to wait long enough for any outstanding traffic to be processed before potential reuse of the port.

Comment: I would expect tcp to be smart enough to figure out the last packet in fraction of seconds, is not it simple, the last packet would say its the last packet. In my example the last packet definitely arrived and still the `TIME_WAIT` state was held for few minutes.